# How do I scrape data from a div-container?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors, python-requests-html

I'm trying to scrape apps names (which exist at the bottom of the website) from [This Website] [1](https://www.workato.com/integrations/salesforce) using requests_html and CSS selectors, but it returns an empty list. Can you please provide an explanation?
The code:

```
import requests_html
from requests_html import HTMLSession

s = HTMLSession()

headers = {
    "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

url = 'https://www.workato.com/integrations/salesforce'

r = s.get(url, headers=headers)

r.html.render(sleep=4)

apps = r.html.find('#__layout > div > div > div > div > div > main > article.apps-page__section.apps-page__section_search > div > div > div.apps-page__integrations > div > ul')

print(apps)
```

I tried the following:

```
for app in apps:
    print(app)
```

and I also used `.text`

but the output always says:

```
[]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you're looking for is embedded in one external JavaScript file (so standard `beautifulsoup` doesn't help here).

To load all applications at once into a pandas DataFrame you can use next example:

```py
import re
import requests
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval

url = 'https://cdn.marie.awsprod.workato.com/mktg-assets/c8ce8de9.js'

html_doc = requests.get(url).text
data = re.search(r'JSON\.parse\(\'(.*?)\'\)', html_doc).group(1)
data = literal_eval(data)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
print(df.head())
```

Prints:

|  | name | title | build_type | categories | aliases | url_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| kissmetrics | kissmetrics | Kissmetrics | unsupported | ['Upcoming'] | nan | nan |
| gusto | gusto | Gusto | custom | ['HR management', 'Staff Management', 'Time and Expense'] | nan | nan |
| adobeexpmgr | adobeexpmgr | Adobe Experience Manager | unsupported | ['Sales'] | nan | nan |
| synthesio | synthesio | Synthesio | unsupported | ['Sales'] | nan | nan |
| teamwork | teamwork | Teamwork | unsupported | ['Sales'] | nan | nan |